# On the nature of a certain property of the sum of divisor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) on odd perfect numbers by Patrick A. Brown titled “A partial proof of a conjecture by Dris”. In this paper, on the first page, the author claims that $\sigma$ has the following property and that it always holds:

$$\frac{(p-1)}{p} \sigma(p^{2b})<p^{2b}\;.$$

This is a property that I was not aware of. Now my question is this:

> Is $p$ always a prime, or can $p$ be a non-prime integer?

Comment: $\sigma(p^{x}) = \sum_{i = 0}^x p^i = 1 + p + \dots + p^x$.   So that $(p - 1)\sigma(p^x) = p + p^2 + \dots p^{x + 1} - (1 + p + \dots + p^x) = p^{x + 1} - 1$, so that $\sigma(p^x)\dfrac{p - 1}{p} = p^x - 1/p \lt p^x$ for all $p \in \Bbb{P}$ and $x \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: For $b=1$ and $p=6$, the inequality does not hold.